# WCF Going from Basic to wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, wshttpbinding

I have gotten my config to work correctly now, there was a mismatch between the actual file structure and the project structure in visual studio. Stupid silly mistake :)

However, now I have the issue of transitioning from basicHttpBinding to WsHttpBinding. This is the webconfig. As you can see I have changed the first endpoint to be of the type wsHttpBinding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RENTIT05ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=rentit.itu.dk;Initial Catalog=RENTIT05;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Rentit05db;Password=omitted" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="RENTIT05Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RentIt.csdl|res://*/RentIt.ssdl|res://*/RentIt.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=rentit.itu.dk;Initial Catalog=RENTIT05;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Rentit05db;Password=omitted;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="10000000"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RentIt05.Services.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.AgeRatingService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IAgeRatingService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.CommentService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.ICommentService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.ItemService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IItemService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.ItemTypeService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IItemTypeService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.LabelService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.ILabelService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.LoginService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.ILoginService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.RatingService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IRatingService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.SectionService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.ISectionService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.StateLogService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IStateLogService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.StateService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IStateService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.UserGroupService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IUserGroupService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.UserService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.IUserService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="RentIt05.Services.TransferService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RentItBinding"  contract="RentIt05.Interfaces.ITransferService"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     <bindings>
       <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="RentItBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
           <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
         </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I try to run this locally on localhost, I get the following error message:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]..
```

I have found some artiles talking about IIS resolving multiple base addresses, but this is locally, so I don't know why it is not working.

Is there something I'm missing here? The config file works fine as long as I only use basicHttpBindings.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, tyvm!

Comment: I edited out the passwords in your config file.  Not a bad idea to make it even more anonymous yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need security enabled?  You have transport security enabled on the wsHttpBinding which will look for ssl.  Your basicHttpBinding isn't using any.  The error will go away if you set

```
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None">

      </security>
    </binding>
```

Another option is to set up ssl on IIS.

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) However, now if I do that and reliable session is false, I get the following error message:
Contract requires Session, but Binding 'WSHttpBinding' doesn't support it or isn't configured properly to support it...
If I set reliable session to true, I get an 405 error (method not allowed)